# How to update a ListView after deleting an item?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

In my application I drag and drop an item from the `ListView` in the trash button and it removes the item. To see the change I have to go back a page and then open again the next page to see that the item was deleted. What I want is when I drop the item to the trash button to show the update the same time.

With the code I have right now, when I go to the page the `ListView` loads for a second and then it disappears.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?
Here is my code:

```
public sealed partial class BasketPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private MobileServiceCollection<Information, Information> tempItem;
    private ObservableCollection<Information> items;
    private ObservableCollection<Information> RefreshedItems { get; set; }
    private IMobileServiceTable<Information> informationTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Information>();
    private Information selectedInformation;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public BasketPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.items = new ObservableCollection<Information>();
        this.refreshedItems = new ObservableCollection<Information>();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        getListData();

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private async void getListData()
    {
        var query = App.conn.Table<Information>();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {

            tempItem = await informationTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Id == item.Name)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

            RefreshedItems.Add(tempItem.ElementAt(0));
        }           
    }
     private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    private void CollectedItemsListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedInformation = (Information)e.ClickedItem;

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaViewPage), selectedInformation);
    }

    private void CollectedItemsListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = string.Join(",", e.Items.Cast<Information>().Select(i => i.Id));
        e.Data.SetText(item);
        e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    }

    private void TrashButton_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }
    }

    private async void TrashButton_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
            var query = App.conn.Table<Information>();
            var itemToDelete = query.Where(p => p.Name == id).FirstOrDefault();

            RefreshedItems.Remove(itemToDelete);

            App.conn.Delete(itemToDelete);
            App.conn.Commit();   
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the binding I do in the XAML file:

```
 <ListView x:Name="CollectedItemsListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding refreshedItems}"
...
```

Comment: it looks like you are setting CollectedItemsListView.ItemsSource multiple times, and the layout is not changing, what about binding ItemsSource?

Comment: I deleted the CollectedItemsListVi‌​ew.ItemsSource  from the TrashButton but still the same, so I am just calling it once.

Comment: don't call it, just use Binding in the xaml, bind the ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection and then every delete, insert and so on (done on this collection) will be properly displayed over the layout

Comment: your code still calls `CollectedItemsListView.ItemsSource = refreshedItems`, as you have bound the item source in xaml you never need to set it in code just update the bound collection

Comment: ok I deleted both 'CollectedItemsListV‌​iew.ItemsSource = refreshedItems', now what do you mean by updating the collection?

Comment: calling Add Remove and Clear as appropriate, in `getListData` you are correctly adding to the collection but nowhere are you removing from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the viewModel is deleting directly from the Model, not itself

i would suggest the following changes

firstly you need to delete or refresh one of your ObservableCollections as part of the delete process (refreshedItems), this will then immediately notify anything bound to it that a change has occurred

so remove `CollectedItemsListView.ItemsSource = refreshedItems;` and update the collection instead

```
refreshedItems.Remove(deletedItem);
```

second remove all setters from the ObservableCollection properties, you need to update the content of the collections not replace the collections

```
public sealed partial class BasketPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MobileServiceCollection<Information, Information> tempItem;
    private ObservableCollection<Information> Items{get;private set;}
    private ObservableCollection<Information> RefreshedItems{get;private set;}
    private IMobileServiceTable<Information> informationTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Information>();
    private Information selectedInformation;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public BasketPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Information>();
        this.RefreshedItems = new ObservableCollection<Information>();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        getListData();

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private async void getListData()
    {
        var query = App.conn.Table<Information>();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {

            tempItem = await informationTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Id == item.Name)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

            RefreshedItems.Add(tempItem.ElementAt(0));

        }
    }

    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    private void CollectedItemsListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedInformation = (Information)e.ClickedItem;

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MediaViewPage), selectedInformation);
    }

    private void CollectedItemsListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = string.Join(",", e.Items.Cast<Information>().Select(i => i.Id));
        e.Data.SetText(item);
        e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    }

    private void TrashButton_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }
    }

    private async void TrashButton_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
            var query = App.conn.Table<Information>();
            var itemToDelete = query.Where(p => p.Name == id).FirstOrDefault();

            RefreshedItems.Remove(itemToDelete);
            App.conn.Delete(itemToDelete);
            App.conn.Commit();   
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As your having trouble with the suggested changes here is a complete working example

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionBindingDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionBindingDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CollectionList x:Name="CollectionList"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Add_Click">add</Button>
        <Button Click="Remove_Click">remove</Button>
        <ListView x:Name="ListVeiw" ItemsSource="{Binding IntegerNumbers}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
namespace CollectionBindingDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionList.Add();
        }

        private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var i = ListVeiw.SelectedItem as int?;
            if(i.HasValue)
                CollectionList.Remove(i.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace CollectionBindingDemo
{
    public class CollectionList
    {
        private Random rnd = new Random();
        public ObservableCollection<int> IntegerNumbers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();


        public void Add()
        {
            IntegerNumbers.Add(rnd.Next(1000));
        }
        public void Remove(int i)
        {
            IntegerNumbers.Remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I removed the CollectedItemsListView.ItemsSource = refreshedItems; I see you added the refreshedItems.Remove(deletedItem); could you explain about this and how do I update the collection? I thought I'm updating the collection by calling the itemsourse again.

Comment: ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged this is used by bindings to detect changes the same way it uses INotifyPropertyChanged to detect property changes so everytime you add or delete to or from the collection the binding automatically picks it up

Comment: check your binding is correct it should be `<ListView x:Name="CollectedItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding RefreshedItems}"` XAML is case Sensitive

Comment: Ok so I have edited the code as you suggested. When I have the ItemsSource="{Bindin‌​g RefreshedItems}" nothing is shown. When I do ItemsSource="{x:Bind RefreshedItems}" I can see the listvview but again I don't see the change when I drop the item in trash. Again I have to go back and the load the page again to see the change.

Comment: With out access to all your code its difficult to say what's not working, i'll knock up a quick demo app and give you a simple working example

Comment: I've edited with the example, notice i've broken the ViewModel out of the CodeBehind this is best practice

Comment: ps thats in c#6 if you have trouble with that tell me and I'll downgrade the code to c#5